# AngularJs $Scope not Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Forgive me for my novelty with Angular but I can't find what the problem to this seemingly simple program.  Instead of the $scope displaying "Jonathan" which is defined LoginController, it displays {{logins.username}} in login.html.  If I move the controller in the index.html, it works fine. When I move it to app.js file, it does not work.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Focusing on LoginController, below is my code:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="millersFormalsApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

     <!-- This add the Angular JS to the program --> 
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- load the logo -->
    <img src="img/millers_icon.png">
</head>
<body>
   <h2> AngularJS Project</h2>        
    <div class="container">

        <div id="menu">
            <a href="Views/home.html" class="btn">Home</a>
            <a href="Views/login.html" class="btn">Login</a>
            <a href="Views/register.html" class="btn">Register</a>
        </div>

        <div ng-view=""></div> 

   </div>         

</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<h2> Login Page</h2>
Username:
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="logins.username"
<br />
Password:
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" ng-model="logins.password"

<h2>Your Username is {{ logins.username }} </h2>
```

**app.js**

```
var millersFormalsApp = angular.module('millersFormalsApp', ['ngRoute']);


//** Route Provider takes care of routing functionality based 
//** upon what has been selected 
millersFormalsApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'Views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/login',
    {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'Views/login.html'
    })
    .when('/register',
    {
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        templateUrl: 'Views/register.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: 'home.html'});
});


//** Controllers are called by the Route Provider to specifically execute
//** the selected item
millersFormalsApp.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) 
    {
        $scope.homePage = "This is Miller's Home Page";

    });

millersFormalsApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.logins = {username: "Jonathan", password: ""};
        console.log($scope);
    });


millersFormalsApp.controller('RegisterController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.register = { firstname: "", lastname: "" };

    console.log($scope);

});
```

Comment: Please post your routing and relevant controller

Comment: it's in the app.js: millersFormalsApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope){

Comment: I mean in the question itself, not in a comment

Comment: if you scroll down in my code, you'll see app.js and then you can find the controller below it.

Comment: can you move you javascripts includes to the bottom of the <body> tag, retry and if fails add the console error from your debugger console?

Comment: It should be `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})`

Comment: Did you reference the all your js scripts correctly?

Comment: your input tags are not closed. Could it be the issue?

Comment: Is the position of the controller definition code important? Does it have to be above the route definition? Just a guess. Never put controllers and route definition in one file. ;) I always use controllerUrl: ...

Comment: @Wayne, as far as I know I did. It seems to me that angular is not properly being pulled into the program.  I referenced them all the same.  I'm using Wamp Server.

Comment: I used the root on the redirect and it did not help

Comment: If you have problems wireing up angular just do the first tutorial and try to extend it by your code: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 ( This is not meant stupid - sometimes one just needs a fresh start! ;) )

Comment: Is it possible to create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co)?

Comment: Could you try to run your not working code and open the console and see if it throws you errors?

Comment: How do you access login page? Should be `<a href="#Views/login.html" class="btn">Login</a>`

Comment: @lujcon, yes that's how I access the login page.  I can also go straight to it by entering the localhost url for it

Comment: your anchors are messing `<a href="#/home" class="btn">Home</a>
            <a href="#/login" class="btn">Login</a>
            <a href="#/register" class="btn">Register</a>` while accessing login page your url should be..like `http://localhost:8000/app/#/login`